# Connecting iPhone to TV

Tags: iphone, lightning

What cable do I need to display my iPhone on my TV?

I have a jailbroken iPhone 3GS running iOS 4.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apple Component AV Cable](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC917ZM/A?fnode=MTY1NDAzOQ&mco=MjAyNDI1ODQ) will let you connect from the iPhone's dock connector to RCA jacks on your TV. It won't be HD.

Standard Disclaimer: Since it's jailbroken, neither I or Apple can guarantee full/any support.

Comment: Do u know of any 3rd party cables that are less expensieve?

Comment: The Griffin A/V is the same, and $35. http://www.griffintechnology.com/products/a-v-cables

Comment: Also worth mentioning that both of these come with an AC adapter.

Comment: i dont think the griffin one is compatible with the iphone.

Comment: I think that it probably is. They may have not updated their specs yet (iPod Touch stops at G3, and there's no reason for that to change). However, it may not be worth the $5 to risk it.

Comment: yeah i guess your right. thnx.